# Starting Cassandra Server Error

Tags: windows, 64-bit, cassandra

I have a problem starting Server, it shows this error on starting.

C:\cassandra107\bin>cassandra
Starting Cassandra Server
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : C:\apache-cassandra-1.0.7\bin\l
ib\jamm-0.2.5.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument

I have Set Envi Variables:

"CASSANDRA_HOME" variable as "C:\cassandra107\bin"
"JAVA_HOME" variable as "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6"

I have another Doubt why is still pointing c:\apache when i have set the Envi Variable as c:\cassandra107

pls help me out thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might want to point CASSANDRA_HOME to "C:\cassandra107" rather than "C:\cassandra107\bin" and start cassandra as "bin\cassandra" in "C:\cassandra107"

Answer (score 3):

I'd use the Windows installer from http://www.datastax.com/products/community instead of trying to run it manually.